# How to extract the file name and change the ending in bash?

Tags: string, bash

I have a bash script that accepts file names that end with `.in`, for example `a1.in` `a2.in`, and I want to take that argument and extract the `a1` and add `.out` to it, how do I do that?

I know accepting an argument is `$1` - but how do I extract the `a1`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To remove a fixed suffix from an argument (or other variable) use `${1%.in}`  -- that will remove the trailing `.in` or do nothing if the argument does not end in `.in`.  To add a suffix, just add it: `${1%.in}.out`

To remove *any* suffix, you can use glob patterns after the `%` like so: `${1%.*}`.  This will remove the shortest matching suffix.  You can remove the longest matching suffix with `%%`: `${1%%.*}`

Answer (score 1):

If your files have only *one* extension:

```
$ echo "a.in" | cut -d '.' -f1
a
```